# Calling $scope.$apply() inside dataBound event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm working on an application that uses AngularJS and Kendo UI. I have in one of my controllers a code similar to this one:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

        var items = [{ text: "Item 1", value: "1" }, { text: "Item 2", value: "2" }];

        $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
           dataTextField: "text",
           dataValueField: "value",   
           dataSource: items,
           index: 0,
           dataBound: function(e) {
              $scope.myVariable = this.value();
              $scope.$apply();
           }
       });
    });
```

As you can see, the dropdownlist widget is being bound to local data.

If I try to run the code, I get the following error: **$rootScope:inprog**.
This error is thrown because there can be only one $apply operation in progress. I'm not calling $scope.$apply() anywhere else in my code, so I assume that the first $apply operation gets called as a result of the controller initialization.

If I remove $scope.$apply() then the program works correctly, but I don't really understand why.

My question is: shouldn't the function, that get's called as a result of the dataBound event, be outside of the Angular context?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the following error: $rootScope:inprog

This because there is still current digestion cycle running and between you can not force it to re-run again.

Instead of `$scope.$apply`,

you can use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

```
$timeout(() => {
  $scope.myVariable = this.value();
}, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I don't really understand why the function, from where I call $scope.$apply(), is being considered to be inside of the Angular context. The program works even if I remove $scope.$apply(). Should I use your method because of some safety reasons?

Comment: Not needed.if it's not in angular context then only go for it